# Bitmap not getting created

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Can anyone tell me why is the Bitmap not getting created even if i am getting it from server?I looked atleast 15 such questions and found every thing almost same but still i cant find the solution.Please try it yourself if you can.The URL is given as well.
There is no error in the program.
Thanks

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ademoproject.appspot.com/retrievedetails");

List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
UrlEncodedFormEntity urlencodedformentity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list);

httppost.setEntity(urlencodedformentity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

Toast.makeText(this,br.readLine(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

byte []image=Base64.decode(br.readLine(), Base64.DEFAULT);

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);

img.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850772/how-to-convert-a-google-charts-graph-to-image-in-android/15850907#15850907) answer help you.

Comment: nope not working.The Imageview is still unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream in = new java.net.URL("your URL as a String").openStream();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

Comment: I have to send some data as well to the server(username,specified in the question).But why is HttpClient not working